# Excel download date format changing in different time zone

Tags: asp.net, excel

**How, i can keep date format same of excel at the time of download in different-2 time zone?**

My downloaded file contains date column format is MM-dd-YYYY.
The issue is that, while i am downloading the excel file in US region it is not converting the dates into different formats, while i am downloading the same file in UK region, it is converting the dates into dd-MM-YYYY.

**Date 12-01-2015 is converting to 01-12-2015.**

I want to keep date format of excel file MM-dd-YYYY in all the regions.
I am generating the file using ASP.Net C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wont just use `formatRange.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy";` solve that problem?

Comment: you may also look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503298/how-to-format-cells-in-excel-sheet-programmatically) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because Excel is selecting the different date format based on the program's locale setting. I would imagine your options are:

a: Change the cell format to what you need in each location, e.g. in VBA the code would be something like `Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy;@"`

b: Store your date data in text format. So literally a text string in mm-dd-yyyy format. You could still easily parse it later.