# How to read Excel and write Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Excel file .Which contains Something like Following

```
Name      Subject       marks
A         Maths                   30  
B         Maths          20  
C         Maths                   60  
D         Maths          35
```

Here the values are not in a proper cell.I want to format the Excel .I want the result like below I mentioned.

```
 Name     Subject       marks
A         Maths          30  
B         Maths          20  
C         Maths          60  
D         Maths          35
```

What I tried is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace excel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\dinesh\sample.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // assume it is the first sheet 
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve my problem.Please give some guidance to solve my issue.Thanks in advance.

[image: Unformated Excel content]

Comment: It would be better to understand if you share a pic of the data in excel sheet.

Comment: Well - what specific problems are you facing? What error do you get?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503298/how-to-format-cells-in-excel-sheet-programmatically

Comment: If you're just starting on this I would recommend looking into the Epplus library rather than using interop.  Interop is not very nice.

Comment: Actually I uploaded an image of Excel file content .I want to Remove the empty columns and create a formated Excel content@Anoop H.N

Comment: It appears to me you need a interop tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: Thanks for Your guidance@Magnetron